# When establishing access to data on a remote database, are views or synonyms preferred?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, dblink

Consider a scenario where you have two databases: On database A you need to access data on database B.

You could create a view on database A that selects from the table on database B.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW Demographics.Employees(
employee_id, employee_dept
)
AS
    SELECT employee_id, employee_dept
    FROM Employee@DB_B;
/
```

Or, you could create a synonym on database A that points to the table on database B.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE SYNONYM Demographics.Employees FOR Employee@DB_B;
```

**What are the advantages and disadvantage to using a view across the DB link versus a synonym across the DB link?**

If the databases are within an Exadata platform, does that change the recommendation?

Comment: I find views harder to tune. Since they can't use index-based joins, they're more opaque to the optimizer. Also I don't think you can use the DRIVING SITE hint against a local view, and it's very helpful in tuning db link queries. I can't think of any disadvantages to using a synonym, so I'd suggest that.

Comment: @kfinity views can't use index-based joins?

Comment: @WilliamRobertson I mean the indexes on tables inside the view are not visible to the optimizer when you're joining the view to something else. More details: https://blogs.oracle.com/optimizer/optimizer-transformation:-join-predicate-pushdown

Comment: Why either?  What is wrong with just putting `FROM Employee@DB_B` in whichever queries need it?  It is helpful to someone looking at a query, maybe for tuning, to know that it is a distributed query.  I would be more interested in putting a view on the remote DB, as kind of a public API for that database, rather than letting remote queries access tables directly, since that makes change impact analysis really difficult.

Comment: @MatthewMcPeak in truth, these remote objects appear in many queries. So if the canonical location of any of these objects ever moved, I want to change as few references as possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the synonym for simplicity.

The view which you have defined is an unnecessary complication if the local database should be seeing all the rows and columns from the remote database.  It adds complexity because there *might* be some additional logic which exists in the view.  Someone seeking to understand the system will need to spend time to examine the view definition and understand it.

Perhaps the view makes things more complicated for the Oracle optimiser.

There are some valid reasons for having a view:

- You want to restrict the columns which are visible
- If new columns are added to the remote table, you do not want them to show up locally
- You want to restrict the rows which are visible, join to other tables, etc.
- You want the view to be invalid if changes are made at the remote site (such as dropping a column) rather than finding out at application runtime

The time for creating the view is when these conditions exist.  Even then, I would make the view select from the synonym.

Comment: "Even then, I would make the view select from the synonym." -- interesting. I presume that is to keep the "@DB_B" portion out of the view definition, thereby making it easier to repoint a dblink as needed (because you'd only need to change the link's definition, and not potentially dozens of object definitions)?

Answer (score 6):

When you create a view over a database link, you're creating an object on the local database. This means you have dictionary information about the remote object, locally.

Whereas the synonym is just a pointer to the remote object. So all you have is the synonym definition.

```
create database link loopback
  using 'localhost/pdb1';

create table t (
  c1 int
);

create or replace synonym s
  for t@loopback;

create or replace view v as 
  select * from t@loopback;

select table_name, column_name, data_type
from   user_tab_cols
where  table_name in ( 'S', 'V' )
order  by table_name, column_name ;

TABLE_NAME   COLUMN_NAME   DATA_TYPE   
V            C1            NUMBER
```

So using a view can be handy if you have tools that inspect the structure of the table (columns, data types, etc.).

On the flip side, because the view is a local object, changes to the remote table aren't automatically propagated:

```
alter table t 
  add ( c2 date ); 

info s

TABLE: T 
     LAST ANALYZED: 
     ROWS         : 
     SAMPLE SIZE  : 
     INMEMORY     :DISABLED 
     COMMENTS     : 

Columns 
NAME         DATA TYPE      NULL  DEFAULT    COMMENTS
 C1          NUMBER(38,0)   Yes              
 C2          DATE           Yes 

info v

Columns 
NAME         DATA TYPE      NULL  DEFAULT    COMMENTS
 C1          NUMBER(38,0)   Yes
```

So you need to re-create the view to see changes. On the flip-flip side this can be an advantage if you don't want remote DDL changes to show up on the local database immediately.

Note that there's no dependency between the local view and the remote table. So breaking changes (such as dropping a column) don't invalidate the view. You'll only find this out when you query it:

```
alter table t
  drop ( c1 );

select status from user_objects
where  object_name = 'V';

STATUS   
VALID    

select * from v;

ORA-00904: "C1": invalid identifier

select * from s;

no rows selected
```

Answer (score 5):

Personally, I would favor the synonym. That's what synonyms are for, giving you a shorter syntax for accessing an object. A view is more for saving a particular query for later reuse. Now, if you wanted to restrict the available columns on the source table or something, that's when you'd use a view.

Answer (score 2):

Synonyms are just pointers to the objects. If the requirement is just accessing the object without the hassle of putting Database link/owner every time, they are the best approach(considering you don't want to restrict column access).

Views are basically a window to the underlying object data. You can be selective in the column access (not possible in synonym) and since the view are based on SQL query, you can do all sorts of online manipulation of data like changing date format, using sql functions(upper, lower, nvl etc..), again which is not possible with Synonyms. You also have option to modify the SQL statement to include more complex SQL statement if requirement arises in the future.

Views are good if you just want to perform fetch and display, if you want to use this in other query, Synonyms are recommended as there is no intermediate SQL layer so data access is faster.

It all boils down to your requirement and the way the object is being used.

Comment: _Synonyms are recommended as there is no intermediate SQL layer so data access is faster_ - assuming the view is just `select * from t@dblink` there's no performance difference between a view & a synonym